# Как вывести массив php в виде многоуровневого списка через html?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$users = array(
    0 => array(
        "name" => "Alex",
        "lastname" => "Petrenko",
        "languages" => array("Java", "Python", "C++")
    ),
    1 => array(
        "name" => "Boris",
        "lastname" => "Vasylenko",
        "languages" => array("PHP", "Ruby", "C++")
    ),
    2 => array(
        "name" => "Vasiliy",
        "lastname" => "Alibabayev",
        "languages" => array("C#", "JavaScript", "HTML", "PHP")
    )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function walk($el) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($el as $k => $v) {
        echo "<li>";
        if (is_array($v)) {
            walk($v);
        } else {
            echo $v;
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```